# Move a dot over circular arc which can move over the arc of the circle for a certain time ,can be stoped

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have to make following Ui, In which when I play this small circle will move in an arc, when I stop it will stop. I can also set the timing of rotation of the small blue circle.

[image]

Till now I have implemented the following code: this gives me an arc of the circle, but I am not able to rotate the smaller circler over the bigger one.

```
 public class CustoCustomProgressBar : View{
    private var path : Path ? =null
    private var mPrimaryPaint: Paint? = null
    private var mSecondaryPaint: Paint? = null
    private var mBackgroundPaint: Paint? = null
    private var mTextPaint: TextPaint? = null
    private var mProgressDrawable : Drawable ? = null
    private var mRectF: RectF? = null

    private var mDrawText = false
    private var mTextColor = 0

    private var mSecondaryProgressColor = 0
    private var mPrimaryProgressColor = 0
    private var mBackgroundColor = 0

    private var mStrokeWidth = 0
    private var mProgress = 0
    var secodaryProgress = 0
        private set

     private  var firstArcprogress = 0
    private var secondArcProgress = 0
    private var thirdArcProgress = 0

    private var mFristArcCapSize = 0
    private var mSecondArcCapSize = 0
    private var mThirdArcCapSize = 0

    private var isFristCapVisible = false
    private var isSecondCapVisible = false
    private var isThirdCapVisible = false

    private var capColor = 0

    private var mPrimaryCapSize = 0
    private var mSecondaryCapSize = 0
    var isPrimaryCapVisible = false
    var isSecondaryCapVisible = false

    private var x = 0
    private var y = 0
    private var mWidth = 0
    private var mHeight = 0

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(context, null)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        init(context, attrs)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    ) {
        init(context, attrs)
    }

    fun init(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        val a: TypedArray
        a = if (attrs != null) {
            context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.CustomProgressBar,
                0, 0
            )
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Must have to pass the attributes")
        }
        try {
            mProgressDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.test)
            mDrawText = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_showProgressText, false)
            mBackgroundColor =
                a.getColor(
                    R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_backgroundColor,
                    resources.getColor(R.color.white)
                )
            mPrimaryProgressColor =
                a.getColor(
                    R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_progressColor,
                    resources.getColor(R.color.white)
                )
            mSecondaryProgressColor =
                a.getColor(
                    R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_secondaryProgressColor,
                    resources.getColor(R.color.black)
                )
            capColor =
                a.getColor(
                    R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_capColor,
                    resources.getColor(R.color.color_9bc6e6_mind)
                )
             firstArcprogress =a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_firstArcProgress, 0)
            mProgress = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_progress, 0)
            secodaryProgress = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_secondaryProgress, 0)
            mStrokeWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_strokeWidth, 10)
            mTextColor = a.getColor(
                R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_textColor,
                resources.getColor(R.color.black)
            )

            mPrimaryCapSize = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_primaryCapSize, 20)
            mSecondaryCapSize = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_secodaryCapSize, 20)
            isPrimaryCapVisible =
                a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_primaryCapVisibility, true)
            isSecondaryCapVisible =
                a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_secodaryCapVisibility, true)

            isFristCapVisible = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_firstCapVisibility, true)
            isSecondCapVisible =
                a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_secodaryCapVisibility, false)
            isThirdCapVisible =
                a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomProgressBar_thirdCapVisibility, false)
        } finally {
            a.recycle()
        }
        mBackgroundPaint = Paint()
        mBackgroundPaint!!.setAntiAlias(true)
        mBackgroundPaint!!.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE)
        mBackgroundPaint!!.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth.toFloat())
        mBackgroundPaint!!.setColor(mBackgroundColor)

        mPrimaryPaint = Paint()
        mPrimaryPaint!!.setAntiAlias(true)
        mPrimaryPaint!!.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE)
        mPrimaryPaint!!.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth.toFloat())
        mPrimaryPaint!!.setColor(capColor)



        mSecondaryPaint = Paint()
        mSecondaryPaint!!.setAntiAlias(true)
        mSecondaryPaint!!.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE)
        mSecondaryPaint!!.setStrokeWidth((mStrokeWidth - 2).toFloat())
        mSecondaryPaint!!.setColor(mSecondaryProgressColor)

        mTextPaint = TextPaint()
        mTextPaint!!.color = mTextColor
        mRectF = RectF()
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        mRectF!![paddingLeft.toFloat(), paddingTop.toFloat(), (w - paddingRight).toFloat()] =
            (h - paddingBottom).toFloat()
        mTextPaint!!.textSize = (w / 5).toFloat()
        x = w / 2 - (mTextPaint!!.measureText("$mProgress%") / 2).toInt()
        y = (h / 2 - (mTextPaint!!.descent() + mTextPaint!!.ascent()) / 2).toInt()

        mWidth = w
        mHeight = h

        invalidate()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        mPrimaryPaint?.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE)
        mSecondaryPaint?.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE)

        // for drawing a full progress .. The background circle
        mRectF?.let {
           mBackgroundPaint?.let { it1 -> canvas.drawArc(it, 270F, 180F, false, it1) } }
        path = Path()
        path?.arcTo(mRectF,270F,180F,true)

        mRectF?.let {
            mBackgroundPaint?.let { it1 ->
                canvas.drawArc(it, 95F, 80F, false, it1)

            }
        }

        mRectF?.let {
            mBackgroundPaint?.let { it1 ->
                canvas.drawArc(it, 180F, 80F, false, it1)
            }
        }
//        // for drawing a secondary progress circle
//        val secondarySwipeangle = secodaryProgress * 360 / 100
//        mRectF?.let { mSecondaryPaint?.let { it1 ->
//            canvas.drawArc(it, 270F, secondarySwipeangle.toFloat(), false,
//                it1
//            )
//        } }
//
        val firstArcProgresSwipeAngle = firstArcprogress * 180 / 100
//        mRectF?.let {
//            mPrimaryPaint?.let { it1 ->
//                canvas.drawArc(
//                    it, 270F, firstArcProgresSwipeAngle.toFloat(), false,
//                    it1
//                )
//            }
//        }

//        // for drawing a main progress circle
//        val primarySwipeangle = mProgress * 360 / 100
//        mRectF?.let { mPrimaryPaint?.let { it1 ->
//            canvas.drawArc(it, 270F, primarySwipeangle.toFloat(), false,
//                it1
//            )
//        } }

//        // for cap of secondary progress
//        val r = (height - paddingLeft * 2) / 2 // Calculated from canvas width
//        var trad = (secondarySwipeangle - 90) * (Math.PI / 180.0) // = 5.1051
//        var x = (r * Math.cos(trad)).toInt()
//        var y = (r * Math.sin(trad)).toInt()
//        mSecondaryPaint?.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL)
//        if (isSecondaryCapVisible) mSecondaryPaint?.let {
//            canvas.drawCircle(
//                (x + mWidth / 2).toFloat(),
//                (y + mHeight / 2).toFloat(),
//                mSecondaryCapSize.toFloat(),
//                it
//            )
//        }

        val r = (height - paddingLeft * 2) / 2
        // for cap of primary progress
        var trad = (firstArcProgresSwipeAngle - 90) * (Math.PI / 180.0) // = 5.1051
        x = (r * Math.cos(trad)).toInt()
        y = (r * Math.sin(trad)).toInt()



        mPrimaryPaint?.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL)
        if (isPrimaryCapVisible) mPrimaryPaint?.let {
            canvas.drawCircle(
                (x + mWidth / 2).toFloat(),
                (y + mHeight / 2).toFloat(),
                mPrimaryCapSize.toFloat(),
                it
            )
        }
        if (mDrawText) mTextPaint?.let {
            canvas.drawText(
                "$mProgress%", x.toFloat(), y.toFloat(),
                it
            )
        }
    }

    fun setDrawText(mDrawText: Boolean) {
        this.mDrawText = mDrawText
        invalidate()
    }

    override fun setBackgroundColor(mBackgroundColor: Int) {
        this.mBackgroundColor = mBackgroundColor
        mBackgroundPaint?.setColor(mBackgroundColor)
        invalidate()
    }

    fun setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth: Int) {
        this.mStrokeWidth = mStrokeWidth
        invalidate()
    }

    fun setSecondaryProgress(mSecondaryProgress: Int) {
        secodaryProgress = mSecondaryProgress
        invalidate()
    }

    fun setTextColor(mTextColor: Int) {
        this.mTextColor = mTextColor
        mTextPaint!!.color = mTextColor
        invalidate()
    }

    var secondaryProgressColor: Int
        get() = mSecondaryProgressColor
        set(mSecondaryProgressColor) {
            this.mSecondaryProgressColor = mSecondaryProgressColor
            mSecondaryPaint?.setColor(mSecondaryProgressColor)
            invalidate()
        }

    var primaryProgressColor: Int
        get() = mPrimaryProgressColor
        set(mPrimaryProgressColor) {
            this.mPrimaryProgressColor = mPrimaryProgressColor
            mPrimaryPaint?.setColor(mPrimaryProgressColor)
            invalidate()
        }


    var progress: Int
        get() = mProgress
        set(mProgress) {
            while (this.mProgress <= mProgress) {
                postInvalidateDelayed(150)
                this.mProgress++
            }
        }

    fun getBackgroundColor(): Int {
        return mBackgroundColor
    }

    var primaryCapSize: Int
        get() = mPrimaryCapSize
        set(mPrimaryCapSize) {
            this.mPrimaryCapSize = mPrimaryCapSize
            invalidate()
        }

    var secondaryCapSize: Int
        get() = mSecondaryCapSize
        set(mSecondaryCapSize) {
            this.mSecondaryCapSize = mSecondaryCapSize
            invalidate()
        }

     var arcprogress: Int
    get() = firstArcprogress
    set(firstArcprogress) {
        while (this.firstArcprogress <= firstArcprogress) {
            postInvalidateDelayed(150)
            this.firstArcprogress = firstArcprogress
        }
    }

    fun getPath(): Path? {
        return path
    }

    fun getXCOORDINTE(): Float{
        return x.toFloat()
    }

    fun getYCoordinate(): Float{
        return y.toFloat()
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use animation for that

Comment: Please elaborate, i tried it with canvas but faced some difficulty.

Comment: what have you done so far. post some code,